# Monthly repeating reminder for date picker IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

I am developing an app which allows you to set monthly reminders for bills,

I have looked through the datepicckers API and can't seem to find how to make it repeat each month.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: Check this link http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-a-reminder-using-uilocalnotification-in-ios-4-objective-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custamize the code according to your need. For details refer [UILocalNotification Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
     UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];    
     localNotification.fireDate = date; //The date and time when the system should deliver the notification.     
     localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
     localNotification.alertBody = alertBody;
     localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
     localNotification.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
     localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
     localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;        
     localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;    
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UILocalNotification APIs

Refer to
http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/